# What should be proper permission of unix socket?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, socket

I have set up nginx to connect to php5-fpm through unix socket instead of tcp. I've read that this has less overhead and hence boost performance. Now I'm wondering what should be the proper permission of the socket to avoid security issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions. 
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0666
listen.owner = nginx ;(or the user that the Nginx is running as)
listen.group = nginx ;(or the group that the Nginx is running as)
listen.mode = 0660
```

Comment: Where is this excerpt from and which is the answer - 666 or 660? And why?

Answer (score 0):

For UNIX sockets, execution permissions do not matter, read and write permission are what matter. So 0660 to restrict the socket to the owner user/group, or 0666 to permit anyone to connect to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).